# How to build JAR files from

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2016

I am using ColdFusion 2016 and want to use this java library from within ColdFusion.

https://github.com/getstream/stream-java

It is not clear what folders are needed to make this work.  I'm very new to doing something specifically like this so please excuse my question if isn't phrased correctly.

I tried downloading the entire zip file from github, renaming it with a .jar extension, and dropping it in my CF classpath but I couldn't seem to instantiate any of the classes.

Answer (score 2):

That's because they're not classes. What you downloaded are the .java source files. Sources must be compiled into *.class files before you can use them. The project is set up for [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven), so you can use an IDE like Eclipse to import the project, then run a Maven build which will compile and create the jar for you.

1. [Download and install Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) with [JDK 1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) or higher (*not* JRE version)
2. Extract the .zip sources to a folder on disk
3. In Eclipse, import the project sources.

   - Select **File > Import > Maven > Existing Maven Projects** then click **Next**
     [image: Eclipse Project Import]
     [image: Existing Maven Project]
   - Click **Browse** and navigate to the folder where you extracted the .zip files. Select the root folder *stream-java-master* and click **Select Folder > Finish**[image: Select Folder]
4. Build the jar

   - Go to Package Explorer, right click the project **stream-core** and select **Run As > Maven Install**
      [image: Eclipse > Maven Install]
   - Check the console for a success/failure message:

     `[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS`
   - The compiled jar will be located in a subdirectory named `/target`. Example:

     `C:\temp\stream-java-master\stream-core\target\stream-core-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar`

If needed, repeat step 4 ("Build a jar") for the other 3 projects.